# SwiftUI: unpublished property of @StateObject causes views redraw

Tags: swiftui

In the Apple's SwiftUI tutorial ['Scrumdinger',](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/managing-state-and-life-cycle) the `ScrumTimer` model publishes three properties, and the `speakers` property is not included.

```
class ScrumTimer: ObservableObject {

    /// The name of the meeting attendee who is speaking.

    @Published var activeSpeaker = ""

    /// The number of seconds since the beginning of the meeting.

    @Published var secondsElapsed = 0

    /// The number of seconds until all attendees have had a turn to speak.

    @Published var secondsRemaining = 0

    /// NOTE: This property is not published.

    private(set) var speakers: [Speaker] = []
}
```

But when we click the 'Next' button in `MeetingFooterView`, which will update `scrumTimer.speakers` array in-place and some other published properties of `scrumTimer`, `MeetingFooterView` gets redrawn.

ScrumTimer:

```
/*
See LICENSE folder for this sample’s licensing information.
*/

import Foundation

/// Keeps time for a daily scrum meeting. Keep track of the total meeting time, the time for each speaker, and the name of the current speaker.
class ScrumTimer: ObservableObject {
    /// A struct to keep track of meeting attendees during a meeting.
    struct Speaker: Identifiable {
        /// The attendee name.
        let name: String
        /// True if the attendee has completed their turn to speak.
        var isCompleted: Bool
        /// Id for Identifiable conformance.
        let id = UUID()
    }
    
    /// The name of the meeting attendee who is speaking.
    @Published var activeSpeaker = ""
    /// The number of seconds since the beginning of the meeting.
   @Published var secondsElapsed = 0
    /// The number of seconds until all attendees have had a turn to speak.
    @Published var secondsRemaining = 0
    /// All meeting attendees, listed in the order they will speak.
    private(set) var speakers: [Speaker] = []

    /// The scrum meeting length.
    private(set) var lengthInMinutes: Int
    /// A closure that is executed when a new attendee begins speaking.
    var speakerChangedAction: (() -> Void)?

    private var timer: Timer?
    private var timerStopped = false
    private var frequency: TimeInterval { 1.0 / 60.0 }
    private var lengthInSeconds: Int { lengthInMinutes * 60 }
    private var secondsPerSpeaker: Int {
        (lengthInMinutes * 60) / speakers.count
    }
    private var secondsElapsedForSpeaker: Int = 0
    private var speakerIndex: Int = 0
    private var speakerText: String {
        return "Speaker \(speakerIndex + 1): " + speakers[speakerIndex].name
    }
    private var startDate: Date?
    
    /**
     Initialize a new timer. Initializing a time with no arguments creates a ScrumTimer with no attendees and zero length.
     Use `startScrum()` to start the timer.
     
     - Parameters:
        - lengthInMinutes: The meeting length.
        -  attendees: A list of attendees for the meeting.
     */
    init(lengthInMinutes: Int = 0, attendees: [DailyScrum.Attendee] = []) {
        self.lengthInMinutes = lengthInMinutes
        self.speakers = attendees.speakers
        secondsRemaining = lengthInSeconds
        activeSpeaker = speakerText
    }
    
    /// Start the timer.
    func startScrum() {
        changeToSpeaker(at: 0)
    }
    
    /// Stop the timer.
    func stopScrum() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        timerStopped = true
    }
    
    /// Advance the timer to the next speaker.
    func skipSpeaker() {
        changeToSpeaker(at: speakerIndex + 1)
    }

    private func changeToSpeaker(at index: Int) {
        if index > 0 {
            let previousSpeakerIndex = index - 1
            speakers[previousSpeakerIndex].isCompleted = true
        }
        secondsElapsedForSpeaker = 0
        guard index < speakers.count else { return }
        speakerIndex = index
        activeSpeaker = speakerText

        secondsElapsed = index * secondsPerSpeaker
        secondsRemaining = lengthInSeconds - secondsElapsed
        startDate = Date()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: frequency, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
            if let self = self, let startDate = self.startDate {
                let secondsElapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - startDate.timeIntervalSince1970
                self.update(secondsElapsed: Int(secondsElapsed))
            }
        }
    }

    private func update(secondsElapsed: Int) {
        secondsElapsedForSpeaker = secondsElapsed
        self.secondsElapsed = secondsPerSpeaker * speakerIndex + secondsElapsedForSpeaker
        guard secondsElapsed <= secondsPerSpeaker else {
            return
        }
        secondsRemaining = max(lengthInSeconds - self.secondsElapsed, 0)

        guard !timerStopped else { return }

        if secondsElapsedForSpeaker >= secondsPerSpeaker {
            changeToSpeaker(at: speakerIndex + 1)
            speakerChangedAction?()
        }
    }
    
    /**
     Reset the timer with a new meeting length and new attendees.
     
     - Parameters:
         - lengthInMinutes: The meeting length.
         - attendees: The name of each attendee.
     */
    func reset(lengthInMinutes: Int, attendees: [DailyScrum.Attendee]) {
        self.lengthInMinutes = lengthInMinutes
        self.speakers = attendees.speakers
        secondsRemaining = lengthInSeconds
        activeSpeaker = speakerText
        print("## reset speakers: \(speakers)")
        print("## reset lengthInMinites: \(lengthInMinutes)")
        print("## reset secondsRemaining: \(secondsRemaining)")
        print("## reset activeSpeaker: \(activeSpeaker)")
    }
}

extension DailyScrum {
    /// A new `ScrumTimer` using the meeting length and attendees in the `DailyScrum`.
    var timer: ScrumTimer {
        ScrumTimer(lengthInMinutes: lengthInMinutes, attendees: attendees)
    }
}

extension Array where Element == DailyScrum.Attendee {
    var speakers: [ScrumTimer.Speaker] {
        if isEmpty {
            return [ScrumTimer.Speaker(name: "Speaker 1", isCompleted: false)]
        } else {
            return map { ScrumTimer.Speaker(name: $0.name, isCompleted: false) }
        }
    }
}
```

MeetingFooterView:

```
struct MeetingFooterView: View {
    let speakers: [ScrumTimer.Speaker]
    var skipAction: ()->Void
    
    private var speakerNumber: Int? {
        guard let index = speakers.firstIndex(where: { !$0.isCompleted }) else { return nil}
        return index + 1
    }
    private var isLastSpeaker: Bool {
        print("### MeetingFooterView updated!")
        print("### speakers is: \(speakers)")
        return speakers.dropLast().allSatisfy { $0.isCompleted }
    }
    private var speakerText: String {
        guard let speakerNumber = speakerNumber else { return "No more speakers" }
        return "Speaker \(speakerNumber) of \(speakers.count)"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            Self._printChanges()
        }
        
        return VStack {
            HStack {
                if isLastSpeaker {
                    Text("Last Speaker")
                } else {
                    Text(speakerText)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: skipAction) {
                        Image(systemName: "forward.fill")
                    }
                    .accessibilityLabel("Next speaker")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding([.bottom, .horizontal])
    }
}
```

MeetingView:

```
struct MeetingView: View {

    @Binding var scrum: DailyScrum

    @StateObject var scrumTimer = ScrumTimer()

    

    private var player: AVPlayer { AVPlayer.sharedDingPlayer }

    

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)

                .fill(scrum.theme.mainColor)

            VStack {

                MeetingHeaderView(secondsElapsed: scrumTimer.secondsElapsed, secondsRemaining: scrumTimer.secondsRemaining, theme: scrum.theme)

                Circle()

                    .strokeBorder(lineWidth: 24)

                MeetingFooterView(speakers: scrumTimer.speakers, skipAction: scrumTimer.skipSpeaker)

//              DebugView(speakers: scrumTimer.speakers)

            }

        }

        .padding()

        .foregroundColor(scrum.theme.accentColor)

        .onAppear {

            print("### .onAppear() run")

            scrumTimer.reset(lengthInMinutes: scrum.lengthInMinutes, attendees: scrum.attendees)

            scrumTimer.speakerChangedAction = {

                player.seek(to: .zero)

                player.play()

            }

            scrumTimer.startScrum()

        }

        .onDisappear {

            scrumTimer.stopScrum()

        }

        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

    }

}
```

The question is: `MeetingFooterView` only depends on `scrumTimer.speakers`, which is an unpublished property, how does it decide to redraw based on whether `scrumTimer.speakers` has changed? I mean, `scrumTimer.speakers` is an unpublished property of @StateObject model and if its value changed, should the view depending on it redraw?

The complete code can be fetched [here.](https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/5e74587b31382e3dbd057b411a6fe771/ManagingStateAndLifeCycle.zip)

Thank you.

===== UPDATE =====

Today when I followed the same tutorial project and in the [next chapter](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/persisting-data), there is a note about `ObservableObject` saying "An ObservableObject includes an `objectWillChange` publisher that emits when one of its `@Published` properties is about to change. Any view observing an instance of `ScrumStore` will render again when the scrums value changes." Since a `@StateObject`'s rawValue **is** an `ObservableObject`, they should work alike.

As a beginner learning SwiftUI my confusion was that whether a `@StateObject` publishes its value changes at **property** level or at **object** level as a whole. I first thought that `@StateObject` publishes its changes at property level, so the published `var secondsElapsed` value change should not cause the MeetingFooterView depending on the unpublished `var speakers` property redraw, even when `speakers` value has changed. But this is wrong. As the note above says, "an `ObservableObject` includes **an**(single) `objectWillChange` publisher that emits when **one** of its `@Published` properties is about to change", this means `@StateObject` delivers its change as a whole object.

With this understanding I get to know why the `speakers` property not having to be `@Published`. When the program runs, `ScumTimer`'s `secondsElapsed` property is updated every single second, and the timer also changes `speakers` value if `secondsElapsedForSpeaker >= secondsPerSpeaker`, which is happening for example every 100 seconds. So even the `speakers` property is not published, its value change will be evaluated every single second because `secondsElapsed` changes every single second, the @StateObject delivers its value change as a whole.

But if we modify its properties like the following, only publishing `speakers` property,

```
    /// The name of the meeting attendee who is speaking.
     var activeSpeaker = ""
    /// The number of seconds since the beginning of the meeting.
     var secondsElapsed = 0
    /// The number of seconds until all attendees have had a turn to speak.
     var secondsRemaining = 0
    /// All meeting attendees, listed in the order they will speak.
    @Published var speakers: [Speaker] = []
```

things will not work. `secondsElapsed` is still updated every second, but since it's not published, `scrumTimer` will not deliver the changes every second. It will only deliver the changes when `speaker`'s value changes, for example when we click the "Next" button.

Comment: what is `scrumTimer.skipSpeaker` that you use in `MeetingFooterView(...)`? Similarly for other variables and functions that are not part of the code for `ScrumTimer` class.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thank you, I edited to include other needed files.

Comment: It's hard to follow what exactly is happening, that's why we usually request a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That said, any view that observes an observable object will be updated (but not necessarily redrawn) when any value in that object changes. SwiftUI will recompute the `body` and will only do a redraw if there's a difference.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thank you, as you said I should've made a minimal, reproducible example to make things simple, sorry. I've figured this issue out and updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `MeetingFooterView`'s body is called twice is speakers array has changed. It's because `ScrumTimer` is first init with no `attendees` which when `attendees.speakers` is called the `isEmpty` check results in an initial default speaker then in onAppear the actual attendees are set thus speakers has been changed. Also if there are no actual attendees a new initial default speaker created again so even in this case the speakers array has still been changed.

```
MeetingFooterView: @self changed.
Printing description of self.speakers:
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : Speaker
    - name : "Speaker 1"
    - isCompleted : false
    ▿ id : 220F9930-E774-4A16-B62F-BF45C0100FDB

MeetingFooterView: @self changed.
Printing description of self.speakers:
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : Speaker
    - name : "John"
    - isCompleted : false
    ▿ id : C53672E2-5043-4364-81E0-C9D44ACDF8CF
```

`printChanges` should have really shown `self.speakers changed` not sure why it didn't.

You can tidy this by removing the ScrumTimer init method and default var lengthInMinutes to 0. Also notice that `DailyScum` has 2 timer vars: `var timer: Timer?` and `var timer: ScrumTimer` in an extension. First remove the extension. Then in onDissapear when the scrum is stopped:

```
let newHistory = History(attendees: scrum.attendees, lengthInMinutes: scrum.timer.secondsElapsed / 60)
```

This call to `scrum.timer` creates a new `ScrumTimer` object!

Should be:

```
let newHistory = History(attendees: scrum.attendees, lengthInMinutes: scrumTimer.secondsElapsed / 60)
```

This sample might have more problems, use it with caution!